# Owner name is not getting populated in LWC by using @wire decorator

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="partnerOpportunityRecordRead">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>partner Opportunity Record Read LWC</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="existingOpportunity" type="String" default="ADD_OPPORTUNITY_ID"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I've created LWC to populate opportunity fields in read-only mode. able to display all fields except opportunity owner. I've gone through multiple solutions provided by salesforce experts & done multiple changes in the js file, still facing the same issue.

.html file:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <!-- Opportunity -->
      <!-- Display -->
        <template if:true={existingOpportunity}>
            <lightning-record-edit-form 
            record-id={existingOpportunity}
            object-api-name={opportunityObject}
            >
            <!-- Messages -->
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
            <br/>
            <!-- Fields -->
                <lightning-accordion active-section-name="A">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Opportunity Details">
                        <div class="slds-grid" style="color:rgb(15, 15, 15); font-weight: bold; font-size:13px">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Opportunity</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={opportunityname}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Account</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={accountname}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="acc slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Channel Partner Deal Stage</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={channelpartnerdealstage}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Owner</label>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text value={Owner}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Close Date</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={closedate}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Storage Product Energy (MWh)</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={storageproductenergymwh}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Storage Product Power (MW)</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={storageproductpowermw}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </lightning-accordion>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </template>

</lightning-card>
```

.js file :

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent }                                from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }                      from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import OWNER_NAME                                        from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Owner.Name';
import Opportunity_OBJECT                                from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import Opportunity_OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD                from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import Opportunity_ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD                    from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Account_Name_Text__c';
import Opportunity_CHANNEL_PARTNER_DEAL_STAGE_FIELD      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Channel_Partner_Deal_Stage__c';
import Opportunity_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD                      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.CloseDate';
import Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_ENERGY_MWH_FIELD      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Opp_Product_Product_Energy_kWh__c';
import Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_POWER_MW_FIELD        from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Opp_Product_Product_Power_kW__c';
export default class PartnerLeadRecordEditForm extends LightningElement {
   @api  existingOpportunity;
   @api  recordID;
    opportunityObject        = Opportunity_OBJECT;
    opportunityname          = Opportunity_OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD;
    accountname              = Opportunity_ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD;
    channelpartnerdealstage  = Opportunity_CHANNEL_PARTNER_DEAL_STAGE_FIELD;
    closedate                = Opportunity_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD;
    storageproductenergymwh  = Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_ENERGY_MWH_FIELD;
    storageproductpowermw    = Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_POWER_MW_FIELD;
    //Owner                    = OWNER_FIRST_NAME;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordID: '$recordID', fields: [OWNER_NAME]})
    Opportunity;

    get Owner() {
      return getFieldValue(this.Opportunity.data, OWNER_NAME);
    }

    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
      if (error) {
          let message = 'Unknown error';
          if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
              message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
          } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
              message = error.body.message;
          }
          this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                  title: 'Error loading opportunity',
                  message,
                  variant: 'error',
              }),
          );
            } else if (data) {
               this.opportunity = data;
               this.Owner = this.opportunity.Owner.Name.value;
            }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest what exactly i'm doing wrong in code. I've tried with putting recordid value in js file still no luck.

I want to display owner name in text format, currently it is showing in hyperlink to user record.

[image]

Comment: Are you using this component on the standard page of the opportunity object?

Comment: i'm using it in community portal... other details already populated except owner name

Comment: is this component directly placed on the community page? or it is wrapped in some other component? Can you add here the meta XML file as well? How are you passing the `recordID` to this?

Comment: @rahulgawale Passing record id on portal itself on block when it prompt to ADD_OPPORTUNITY_ID. have added snap in question where you can see recordID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent }                                from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }                      from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import OWNER_NAME                                        from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Owner.Name';
import Opportunity_OBJECT                                from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import Opportunity_OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD                from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import Opportunity_ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD                    from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Account_Name_Text__c';
import Opportunity_CHANNEL_PARTNER_DEAL_STAGE_FIELD      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Channel_Partner_Deal_Stage__c';
import Opportunity_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD                      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.CloseDate';
import Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_ENERGY_MWH_FIELD      from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Opp_Product_Product_Energy_kWh__c';
import Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_POWER_MW_FIELD        from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Opp_Product_Product_Power_kW__c';

const fields = : [OWNER_NAME];

export default class PartnerLeadRecordEditForm extends LightningElement {
   @api  existingOpportunity;
   @api  recordId;
    opportunityObject        = Opportunity_OBJECT;
    opportunityname          = Opportunity_OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD;
    accountname              = Opportunity_ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD;
    channelpartnerdealstage  = Opportunity_CHANNEL_PARTNER_DEAL_STAGE_FIELD;
    closedate                = Opportunity_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD;
    storageproductenergymwh  = Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_ENERGY_MWH_FIELD;
    storageproductpowermw    = Opportunity_STORAGE_PRODUCT_POWER_MW_FIELD;
    //Owner                    = OWNER_FIRST_NAME;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields})
Opportunity;

get ownerName() {
  return getFieldValue(this.Opportunity.data, OWNER_NAME);
}

wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
  if (error) {
      let message = 'Unknown error';
      if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
          message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
      } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
          message = error.body.message;
      }
      this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
              title: 'Error loading opportunity',
              message,
              variant: 'error',
          }),
      );
        } else if (data) {
           this.opportunity = data;
           this.Owner = this.opportunity.Owner.Name.value;
        }
   }
 }
```

// HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <!-- Opportunity -->
      <!-- Display -->
        <template if:true={existingOpportunity}>
            <lightning-record-edit-form 
            record-id={existingOpportunity}
            object-api-name={opportunityObject}
            >
            <!-- Messages -->
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
            <br/>
            <!-- Fields -->
                <lightning-accordion active-section-name="A">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Opportunity Details">
                        <div class="slds-grid" style="color:rgb(15, 15, 15); font-weight: bold; font-size:13px">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Opportunity</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={opportunityname}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Account</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={accountname}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="acc slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Channel Partner Deal Stage</label>
                                    <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={channelpartnerdealstage}></lightning-output-field>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Owner: [![enter image description here][1]][1]</label>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text value={ownerName}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Close Date</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={closedate}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Storage Product Energy (MWh)</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={storageproductenergymwh}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Storage Product Power (MW)</label>
                                        <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={storageproductpowermw}></lightning-output-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </lightning-accordion>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </template>

</lightning-card>
```

This is working:

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure, this will not work.

Comment: Well, I tested and it does

Comment: Did you test this in community page?

Comment: Hey @CarlosNaranjo , it does work for me as well, just made few changes in js file, wire decorator to pass existingopportunity. Also in html file have made changes like below
<div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
<label>Owner</label>
{ownerName}
</div>
but it is showing me value in bold..Can we make normal text, instead of bold letters.

Comment: Check the LDS for changes to your text. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/text/ there you can select what ever suits you better and add it to your div class

Comment: have done changes in css file & it did work. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here in the wired property.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordID: '$recordID', fields: [OWNER_NAME]})
Opportunity;
```

You are passing `recordID` which you have not defined anywhere. You have passed the record id in the `existingOpportunity` property of your component. Also, the parameter name for `getRecord` is invalid(`recordID`), it should be `recordId` instead.

So you need to change the wired property as below

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$existingOpportunity', fields: [OWNER_NAME]})
Opportunity;
```

---

### Apart from the above problem here are some things you can do in a better way.

Instead of `existingOpportunity`, you could have used more realistic name to the id like `recordId` or `existingOpportunityId`. Personally, I would prefer `recordId`

`recordID` was not needed as you already had `existingOpportunity`.

Comment: hey rahul.. I've tried but it didnot work. Done changes as you mentioned & for HTML included this.
<div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
<label>Owner</label>
<lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name={Owner}></lightning-output-field>
 </div>

Comment: @rahulgawale  no nice to say something is not working if you haven't tested first .. check my update .. BOOM!! :)

Comment: @Snehal please try now.

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo I believe you tested it on the standard page, not community. It will work on the standard page, I know.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find the issue is to check the data log values and use the relevant property from the JSON.

In the following JSON output from **console.log(data)**:

```
fields{
   Name: {displayValue: null, value: "Sample Account"}
   Owner: {displayValue: "User User", value: {…}}
}
```

The best way to access the Owner's Name is through the displayValue field.

**`data.fields.Owner.displayValue`** - should work in this case.